# Downloading and saving all the images reading the url Array

Tags: android, foreach, picasso

I am trying to download and save all the images from a url array but the problem is only last image gets saved with the name img7.jpg. I don't understand where the problem is? I want all the images to be downloaded and saved with the name img1.jpg, img2.jpg, img3.jpg and so on. Where in the code do I need to make changes?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ImageView imageView;

public static String[] stringArray = {"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/90/Broken_Boundaries_of_Rohtas_Fort.jpg",
                                      "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a0/Rohtas_View_4.jpg",
                                      "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/07/Rohtas_Fort_Gate.jpg",
                                      "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/78/Rohtas_Village_View_2nd.jpg",
                                      "http://www.worldheritagesite.org/picx/w586.jpg",
                                      "http://wpcontent.answcdn.com/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/68/Rani_Mahal_Rohtas_Fort_2.jpg/930px-Rani_Mahal_Rohtas_Fort_2.jpg",
                                      "http://photos.wikimapia.org/p/00/01/75/75/69_big.jpg"};
int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    for (String url : stringArray){

        Picasso.with(this)
        .load(url)
        .into(target);

        i++;
    }

}

private Target target = new Target() {

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/img"+i+".jpg");
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                    }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
        if (placeHolderDrawable != null) {

        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: I'd recommend you use `HttpUrlConnection` or some Http library to download files instead, as Picasso is not really designed for downloading.

Comment: That is bit complex whereas Picasso does the same work in one line that's why I went for Picasso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case Picasso loads your images asynchronously. What means, that

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load(url)
    .into(target);
```

isn't waiting until your picture is downloaded and stored to disk. So, your counter `i` is always `(stringArray.length - 1)`, if it comes to saving the image.

Do something like this:

```
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    int index = 0;
    for (String url : stringArray) {
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .into(new IndexTarget(index));
        index++;
    }
}

class IndexTarget implements Target {

    private final int mIndex;

    public IndexTarget(int index){
        this.mIndex = index;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/img"+mIndex+".jpg");
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it serves the purpose. Is there a way I can resize first and then download the images because it is taking too long to download?

Comment: It is not possible to resize an image before you download it.